# How to denote the set of all students who take the same class as some given student $s'$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set of Students: $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_2 \}$. Now each student
takes some class (doesn't matter what class).
Now I need to have a set $X$ that contains all students that take the same
class, for some given student $s'$:

Is $X$ correctly defined: $X = \{ s : \forall s \in S(s.class = s'.class \wedge s \neq s')\}$ ??
Or do you have some more elegant solution (if mine is correct)?

Comment: The so-called *set-builder* notation $\{ x | \varphi(x) \}$ "binds" the variable $x$; so, you have not to quantify it in the "defining condition" $\varphi(x)$.

Comment: I get it, that is: $X= \{ s: s \in S(s.class = s.class \wedge s \neq s')\}$

Comment: nevertheless, is X correctly built?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the $s.class$ notation ... but if it stay for "the class to which $s$ belongs", I think it works. Only one note : are you sure that it is correct to exclude $s'$ from the set $X$ of classmates of $s'$ ?

Comment: Yes, I need to exclude it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots, s_n\}$ be the set of students and $C$ be the set of available classes. Denote by $c(s)$ the class student $s$ takes. Given a particular student $s'$ the set $X$ of all students that take the same class as $s'$ is denoted by
$$X:=\bigl\{s\in S\>\bigm|\> c(s)=c(s')\bigr\}\ .$$
Here the chosen student $s'$ is a member of $X$. If you do not want that you can define the set
$$\dot X:=\bigl\{s\in S\>\bigm|\> s\ne s' \ \wedge \ c(s)=c(s')\bigr\}\ .$$